# How create users per enviroment using ansible Inventory and module "htpasswd"

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm newbie in ansible. I wrote ansible role for creating user and password in "*/etc/httpd/.htpasswd*" like that:

```
- name: htpasswd
  htpasswd:
    path: /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
    name: dev
    password: dev
    group: apache
    mode: 0640
  become: true
```

Now, I'm trying to understand, how I can set user and password placeholder variable per environment for this model using inventory(or any other way). Like, if I ran "ansible playbook -i inventories/dev" so in role of this model could be set:

```
- name: htpasswd
  htpasswd:
    path: /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
    name: "{{ inventory.htpasswd.name }}"
    password: "{{ inventory.htpasswd.password }}"
    group: apache
    mode: 0640
  become: true
```

And in inventory folder per environment will be file "htpasswd" with name and password content like that:

```
name: dev
password: dev
```

Does Ansible have something like that? Or can someone explain me what best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, each host is assigned to a `all` group by Ansible. With the following structure you can define group vars based on inventory.

- inventories/dev/hosts
- inventories/dev/group_vars/all.yml
- inventories/staging/hosts
- inventories/staging/group_vars/all.yml

In `inventories/dev/group_vars/all.yml`:

```
name: dev
password: dev
```

In `inventories/staging/group_vars/all.yml`:

```
name: staging
password: staging
```

And then in your tasks, reference the vars with their names:

```
- name: htpasswd
  htpasswd:
    path: /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
    name: "{{ name }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    group: apache
    mode: 0640
  become: true
```

Comment: And how I can call this variable in task?  {{ group_vars.name }}?

Comment: No, just reference the var with `{{ password }}`